# Android db data vs file name reference

Tags: android, sqlite, filenames

I've seen this alot and was hoping someone could answer this,
I'm not a institutionally trained coder , I'm very much self taught.

Now the Question is:
I've seen quite a few apps that save a pic reference as one thing but the actual name is something else (as an example)

So in the database a pic would be called :

bc019dc622bfb2b3d6352354f95d5d8fa5a88860491e6bfe0bfd72076c763a74

but the actual Pic is :

ce15ec75764bb83d7ed38cd53c36bd.jpg

I think its hex but cannot figure out how one matches to the other.. This is the only reference there is. No where else is a reference to this pic.

This is not limited to just a pic.
I'm interested in this as I would like to incorporate such code aswell in future projects.

Comment: Looks like a 256-bit hash and a 120-bit hash. How they are computed depend really on the app.

Comment: I think too that it's hash or some encoding. Can you post more details about this pictures and their names?

Comment: what would you like to know ? What shall I fetch ?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer ..

It's a md5 hash !
Thanks for pointing me into the right direction guys !!
I used an online calculator
https://quickhash.com/

Input:

bc019dc622bfb2b3d6352354f95d5d8fa5a88860491e6bfe0bfd72076c763a74

Output:

0ce15ec757640bb83d7ed38cd53c36bd

minus the first zero and Bam !!